# Laravel 5.5 submitted information in form not saving to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

I'm trying to submit a user to the database through a registration form. It all seems fine apart from the *small issue* of not saving ANY of the details. The migration has set up all of the correct tables but nothing gets saved.

This is my `database.php`

```
    'mysql' => [
        'read' => [
            'host' => '192.168.1.1',
        ],
        'write' => [
            'host' => '192.168.1.2'
        ],
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'actorthing'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'root'),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

And this is my [Create Users Table](https://gist.github.com/Sulcalibur/348d38d3d88a239e744be88dcf8a2932)

Any guidance on this would be super helpful.

Many thanks.

Edit:
Sorry, great point, too busy rushing. This is the [register.blade.php page](https://gist.github.com/Sulcalibur/60a7e1be4748d34592250bb5d6da60ce)

Comment: post the code where you are trying to persist the records

Comment: Also worth checking if you have any Request validation rules as well as posting the code Sapnesh suggested.

Comment: Sorry, great point, too busy rushing. This is the [register.blade.php page](https://gist.github.com/Sulcalibur/60a7e1be4748d34592250bb5d6da60ce)

Comment: Are you doing the registration in your own controller? If so please post the method where you are persisting the data. If you use $request->all() make sure that the name of the input fields is exactly the same as your database columns. Make sure you have setup mass assignable fields,...

Comment: It looks like you are submitting `Last_Name` in your form and the database table is expecting `Surname`. Also your `Date_Created` field is not nullable so if you're not passing that in the controller the record will not create.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that just before and edited it, thanks, @HelloSpeakman :)

Now for that `Date_Created` nullable issue.

Comment: Balls! Now this:

                Illuminate\Database\QueryException thrown with message 
                "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'Date_Created' doesn't 
                have a default value (SQL: insert into `users` (`First_Name`, `Surname`, 
                `Email`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Testing, Surname, 
                sul@******.co.uk, 2018-02-15 12:10:03, 2018-02-15 12:10:03))"

Comment: In your migration you can set a default like this `$table->dateTime('Date_Created')->default(DB::raw('NOW()'));` or if you're using Carbon just use `$table->dateTime('Date_Created')->default(Carbon::now());`

Comment: All working now. Thank you @HelloSpeakman + sapnesh-naik, christophvh :)